# How can databases guarantee persistency if it eventually depends to OS?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, windows, file

When we issue an SQL statement as far as I know the default behavior in databases (for sure in MySQL) is auto-commit.
But the structure is usually as follows:

```
String sqlInsertOrUpdateStatement = "....";  
sqlStatement.execute(sqlInsertOrUpdateStatement);  
//rest of code
```

Now the `execute` is a blocking function and when it returns we know that the the data was saved or not (according to the result of the execute).
But what I can not understand is the following:
All DB implementations use files in the lowest level. And e.g. an `INSERT` is basically deep down a write operation to a file. But when we write to a file I believe the contents are actually not flushed immediately. They are flushed when OS decides. Even if the application code (e.g. the C library) issues a flush even then the OS will flush the data *soon*.
So how can databases **guarantee** the persistency. Is there something basic in file I/O and OS I am overlooking/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3):

Well, on Linux databases management systems use the `fsync` call, which actually does that: Guarantee, that the data is written *to disk*. Some big systems like Oracle also skip the filesystem (which does the things you referred to as done by the OS) and write to sectors on the drive themselves (improving the speed, of course).

And if you want to question durability... hard drives also may fail, even in bulk ;-)

Comment: So only Oracle and DBs in Linux *guarantee* persistency?

Comment: You can't say that. Other operating systems provide similar functionality, of course, and other database systems use similar techniques. These are just examples I know of, but I'm pretty sure MySQL also guarantees durability.

Comment: How can you bybass the filesystem?With special write priviliges and a lot of assembly?

Comment: no, way easier: with administrative access (`root`) you can just open the block device representing your hard drive (or the partition) and write to it. You don't need any assembly for that... Again, no clue how it is done in windows, but in Linux it's easy: Just `fopen("/dev/sda1/", "r")` and you're all set.

Comment: This implies the db runs with root access.I was under the impression that this is frowned upon (not to say forbidden) for security reasons.Does this mean that installing the DB in root makes it more reliable in write operations? Also that if installed in non-root the db uses a different layer to interact with the FS?

Comment: You shouldn't generalize. I'm talking just about possibilities, not facts. Direct drive access is not giving you more reliability, but speed, as a layer is skipped, and complexity with it. You _can_ configure Oracle to behave that way, you don't have to. And it certainly doesn't do it out-of-the-blue. And besides, every webserver has root privileges at least once, when it boots up (Port 80 is privileged). So the DBMS may open the drive, and drop the privileges (this is current best practice, until Capabilities are available everywhere).

Answer (score 3):

Databases don't guarantee anything, they don't control the entire stack from databases to bits in storage, so how can they?

What they can do is assure that they're calling the appropriate functions that, if assumptions hold, will maintain durability.

The way it works, is the program makes a write to the database. The database (typically) convert that write operation in to a log event, and then calls fsync to flush the log buffers to disk.

But see, there are several abstractions involved here. The first one is the buffering at the database level. DB updates the log buffers with the appropriate information, then write those buffers to some kind of I/O stream.

If they were written using stdio, which again buffers the data (unlikely, but who knows), then they would have to call flush on that stream to force the system call to write the buffers "to disk".

However, as you observed, writing to "disk" means writing to yet more buffers. So, the fsync call is a lower level equivalent of stdio's flush call. It tells the OS to write the processes data out to disk. But what does that really mean? It means the OS calls the appropriate device driver to write the underlying blocks to the physical device.

Well, the device driver can say "Okey dokey" and not do anything at all. They typically don't, but they can. The driver can do whatever it wants. What we assume happens is that the driver takes the buffers of data, then starts talking to the hardware over the appropriate interface (SATA, SCSI, iSCSI, NFS, USB, etc.).

The nut here is that in the end, what is the driver actually talking to? Well, today, with modern SATA drives, it's talking to Yet Another computer. This computer is the controller for the disk drive.

And you know what controllers on disk drives do? They buffer data in to RAM. So, it's possible you can be doing "everything right" (stdio flush, fsync, driver write to block devices) and STILL have the data, in RAM, waiting to fail, sitting on some $50 hard drive that said "AOk boss!".

Some drives default to saying "okey dokey" and simply storing the data in a buffer, and need to be configured otherwise. Other drives default to doing the right thing out of the box. If you use the former kind of drives, improperly configured, for a database, or a RAID system, well, yolks on you if you lose power.

Or the device will configured correctly and happily write the block on bad sector, and you were doomed from the start. C´est la vie.

Also, consider if you're talking to a driver, that talking to network, that's talking to a SAN controller, that using battery backed up RAM caches before writing to the array...hopefully.

So, the databases don't guarantee anything. Rather, they do due diligence that SHOULD get the data to the actual physical devices, safely, and where that data will actually, finally, persist.

Any database worth their salt that says that they do ACID does this, and all operating systems support this -- all OS'es that anyone would actually use, of course.

Bottom line, if you want to make sure your data is on a disk, in Unix, you call fsync. In Windows you call "whatever google says you call for fsync on Windows". What actually happens is out of you hands at that point, so best to ask questions to those that know your hardware and your interfaces. The program, however, is done.

Addenda:

The way a modern DB typically works, is that you have your data organized on disk in "tables", and, typically, separately, as "indexes". So, you can imagine that if you have a table with 1000 rows, that's stored on the disk in 100 "pages", you can see how if you updated the 500th row, you would need to update the 50th page. You can also see that if you updated rows 700, 500, 600, you'd need to update the 70th, 50th, and 60th page.

Well, it turns out that disks drives work very quickly as a streaming device. When you have to move the disk head, the arm that goes back and forth on a drive, it can slow things down dramatically. So you can see in the example above, the disk head bouncing back and forth during that write operation.

Now, a database with transactions also requires some kind of log. The log is where all of the operations are recorded. The log is also typically only appended to, so if you were to update those rows above, they'd be captured in the log as 3, sequential events.

So what the DB does is, when you change a row, it will update the internal buffers, i.e. the internal copy of the 50th page. When the DB wants to go and get another copy of the 500th row, it will see it already has a copy in RAM, and not need to go to the disk. Once it updates the internal buffers, it will right the operations to the log. Since these are sequential, they're much faster. Finally, it will commit the write using the fsync etc. It does that right away, every time you commit a transaction. You can't commit the transaction until you're "sure" the data is recorded somewhere.

At this point, you have the row in memory, the row captured in the log (durably), but the actual page on the disk is out of date. For a running DB, this is not a problem. Eventually, the system will "checkpoint". That takes all of the log entries that are out of date, and they're copied to their final destination on the disk, syncing up the logs, the buffers, and the disk. When it does this, it will sort the writes to the disk. So above rather than writing the 60th, then 50th, then 70th page, it'll write them in order: 50, 60, 70. Less head seek, better performance.

Now, if the system crashes before that happens, that's no problem. We already have the data safely in the log. So when the system comes back up, it goes in to "recovery". Recovery is basically running the checkpoint process on all of the data in the log that has been committed (i.e. their transaction was completed), and flushes them out to the disk pages as before. It will do this BEFORE lettings the DB come up and be accessible.

As for configuring the drives, as I understand it there's some utilities that write parameter configurations to the drives. Depends on the OS, I don't really know the details. You'll have to google about for it.

Comment: +1.Thank you for this detailed description!I have a couple of questions 1)`database (typically) convert that write operation in to a log event, and then calls fsync to flush the log buffers to disk` What do you mean by log event? 2) This log event is buffered, the thread returns back to the caller and the log event is `fsynced` *eventually*?I am not sure I follow you on this. 3)`If you use the former kind of drives, improperly configured, for a database` It is the first time I hear this.How do you set this configuration?E.g. like settings from OS? (e.g. right click on the disk?)

Comment: Very interesting update!There is 2 parts I don't understand.1)You mention about a separate log file and the actual files that "implement" the tables.Then you mention that when the data are eventually are written to the latter place (the actual location) we have the advantage to have the writes to disk sorted and hence better performance.But aren't the sorting of writes only done by the device controller? Can we do sorting of writes at the application level which we are at your description? 2)These log files are extra storage.Are they ever deleted to release space?